# How do I change :after on a WordPress navigation when user scrolls down?

Tags: javascript, css, wordpress

I want to change the :after on my menu after the user scrolls down, After more failures this is what I'm trying to get working:

Script:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var a = 50px;
    var pos = $(window).scrollTop();
    if(pos > a) { $('.current_page_item').addClass('transparent') }
</script>
```

CSS:

```
.nav-menu .current_page_item:after {
    content: "";
    display: block;
    width: 0;
    border: 10px solid rgba(35, 31, 32, 1);
    border-color: rgba(35, 31, 32, 1) transparent transparent transparent;
    position: absolute;
    top: 100%;
    left: 50%;
    margin-left: -10px;
}

.nav-menu .current_page_item.transparent:after {
    content: "";
    display: block;
    width: 0;
    border: 10px solid rgba(35, 31, 32, 0.8);
    border-color: rgba(35, 31, 32, 0.8) transparent transparent transparent;
    position: absolute;
    top: 100%;
    left: 50%;
    margin-left: -10px;
}
```

Is this getting close to the answer or am I still doing this wrong?

Thanks for any advice.

Answer (score 1):

`var a = 50px;` will throw a syntax error. `scrollTop()` returns an integer. To add the class, use:

```
var a = 50,
    pos = $(window).scrollTop();

if(pos > a) 
{ 
    $('.current_page_item').addClass('transparent');
}
```